# Spring Scope as singleton working

Tags: spring, scope

In below example I am not very much clear as of what is happening

```
 <bean id="triangle" class="com.mkyong.Triangle" scope="singleton">
<property name ="pt1" ref ="point1" />
<property name ="pt2" ref ="point2"/>
<property name ="pt3" ref ="point3"/>
</bean>

<bean id="triangle1" class="com.mkyong.Triangle" scope="singleton">
<property name ="pt1" ref ="point1" />
<property name ="pt2" ref ="point2"/>
<property name ="pt3" ref ="point3"/>
</bean>
```

I am seeing two instances of Triangle Object. How Internally Spring handle this?
I know Spring is using Reflection. What's the point in using singleton because its behaving like prototype(giving me two Triangle object). If the concept of scope lies for a same id(either triangle or triangle1) then it should be defined as single object per id per spring container per classloader per jvm instead of single object per spring container per classloader per jvm

Answer (score 1):

Defining a bean as singleton does not mean that it will only be one instance of that class. The singleton scope applies to the bean definition, so you will have two singleton beans of type triangle.

Comment: So in case of Spring singleton it is single Object per id defined in spring config file per spring container per jvm.

Comment: Looks like Spring internally uses a Map for ids and Object as values?  For different ids i get different objects.

Comment: Yes, singleton per bean definition pr application context.

Answer (score 0):

It will have one single instance for triangle1 or another single instance for triangle2.

> When a bean is a singleton, only one shared instance of the bean will
>   be managed, and all requests for beans with an id or ids matching that
>   bean definition will result in that one specific bean instance being
>   returned by the Spring container.

You can check more information at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton